Getting file data access from anywhere in Flutter Desktop app
I am currently developing a Flutter application and I am facing an issue when trying to read a file from a specific directory on my desktop device.
Read Code:
Future<void> readData() async {
  var dir = Directory.fromUri(Uri.directory(
      'This PC/Redmi Note 10/Internal shared storage/Android/data/com.example.mobile_app/files'));
  // Read the file
  var file = File('${dir.path}file.txt');
  print(file.path);
  String contents = await file.readAsString();
  print(contents);
}

Error:

Cannot open file, path = 'This PC/Redmi Note 10/Internal shared
storage/Android/data/com.example.mobile_app/files/file.txt' (OS Error:
The system cannot find the path specified.

I know I am unable to access such files but is there any way to access file which is outside C drive.
